# Gradle - StopExecutionException doesn't change TaskStatus

Tags: gradle

I have three gradle Tasks: A, B and B2. They depend on each other in the following way: A <- B <- B2 (meaning B depends on A and B2 depends on B). Here is my code:

```
task A {
    println "Exec A"
}

task B(dependsOn: A) << {
    throw new StopExecutionException("skip this task") // this exception prevents the println, but doesn't change the TaskStatus of B
    println "Exec B"
}

task B2(dependsOn: B) << {
    println "Did work: " + B.getState().getDidWork();
    println "Exec: " + B.getState().getExecuted();
    println "Failure: " + B.getState().getFailure();
    println "Skip message: " + B.getState().getSkipMessage();
    println "Skipped: " + B.getState().getSkipped();

    println "Exec B2"
}
```

When I execute this (by running `gralde -q B2`), I get the following output:

```
> gralde -q B2
Exec A
Did work: true
Exec: true
Failure: null
Skip message: null
Skipped: false
Exec B2
```

As can be seen, the properties of the TaskState didn't change although the StopExecutionException was thrown correctly. How can I determine in a task if all former tasks were executed completely?

Answer (score 2):

`StopExecutionException` is simply a shortcut to finish the task execution. The task doesn't fail if it is thrown as you can read in [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/StopExecutionException.html) neither is the task skipped. You can throw `GradleException` to make the task fail and then the subsequent task will be able to check the result. Note that you will need to change B2 to make it a finalizing task of B (see [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)) or play with `runAfter` or something similar.

Comment: Stopping the excectuion of task B is intended. What I want to know is if I can somehow stop the task in a task action (not in the onlyIf block) and check in a follow-up task if all previous tasks could finish successfully. Do you have any idea on this? Thanks in advance.